# Set (custom) fields in Elastic APM for Python with Flask

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask, kibana, elastic-stack

I am quite new to Elastic APM, Kibana, Elasticsearch and APM in general and did not come across any information pointing towards my needs. I set up the `elastic-apm[flask]` module and followed the tutorial. In the Kibana dashboard I get information like response times and server name, but the fields for client.ip etc. are empty. I would like to track the IP addresses (more exactly where my website visitors come from).

So, how do I get the user's IP address into the client.ip field in Elastic APM? I don't want to issue an `app.logger.debug` statement everytime a route is being requested.

Comment: Well, it turns out, the field does actually already exist (at least if not issuing from the same localhost). It is called "http.request.env.REMOTE_ADDR". The core question about sending info determined at request time remains, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to modify your elastic APM python agent code. 
In general, you can add labels to your span example

```
elasticapm.label(key1=value1, key2=value2)
```

also, you can add directly to span object.

You will get the ip from request object flask

`request.remote_addr`  set this to the desired key.

more details of APIs on elastic APM python agent can be found here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/api.html

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question after so many months! Upvote for this.A little story 'bout me: I've turned from Elastic to Grafana. It's easier to use than the Elastic Stack if you're coming from Python and if you need to log data. I use Statsd (which has excellent bindings for Python) -> Carbon Cache (assembling data over time) -> Graphite (Analyzes your data and acts as the data source for Grafana) -> Grafana (graphical data dashboard). For really professional projects though, I can highly recommend the complex but powerful Elastic Stack. Thanks for your answer!